Is it okay to not connect the bottom thermal pad of esp32 wroom to ground?
The bottom thermal pad (epad) of esp32 wroom is left floating instead of connected to gorund.
I looked at the datasheet and found out that I need to connect it to gnd.
The pcb works, but I'm worried.
Is it okay if I don't connect the thermal pad to gnd?

Where does it say that the EPAD needs to be connected to ground? The datasheet of the ESP32-WROOM-32(U)E says this on page 24:

Soldering EPAD Pin 39 to the ground of the base board is not a must, however, it can optimize thermal performance. If you choose to solder it, please apply the correct amount of soldering paste.

Generally, thermal pads should be connect, but it's probably not a critical error in this case.
